# Python implementation of Gaussian Process with monotonicity constraints?

Tags: python, gaussian-process

I am looking for a python library that implements Gaussian Process (GP) with monotonic constraints as the underlying function I am trying to approximate is known to me as monotonic. I am aware of the papers that talk about possible techniques, but couldn't find any python implementations. And I am not inclined to implement those papers and is only looking for a working implementation. Please share any GP library that facilitates apply monotonic constraints.